# Howto combine onclick-Event with options in innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I want to combine a button with onclick function in a innerHTML

Button (for phonegap project)

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Message, image and link', null, 'https://www.adsf.org/logo.png', 'http://www.adsf.org')">message, image and link</button>
```

But how to use into a innerHTML?

```
$(".ergebnisSkill").append('<!-- HERE MY BUTTON?? -->');
```

I can only one time use `""` and `''`

How to combine these two things?

Comment: Try with escaping quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to escape the ' by placing \ in-front of it

```
$(".ergebnisSkill").append('<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share(\'Message, image and link\', null, \'https://www.adsf.org/logo.png\', \'http://www.adsf.org\')">message, image and link</button>');
```